# F# Static Methods In Class

Tags: f#, static, function, class

I'm trying to figure out how to make static methods in a class in F#. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Don't forget the online docs! [Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483468(VS.100).aspx) has this info, and [F# Language Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233181(VS.100).aspx) is a general good starting point to find info about the language syntax.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Sure, just prefix the method with the *static* keyword. Here's an example:

```
type Example = class
  static member Add a b = a + b
end
Example.Add 1 2

val it : int = 3
```

Comment: It would be great if you can update your answer with light syntax (so, no need to use the "end" keyword)

Answer (score 8):

If you wanted to have static methods in a static class, then use Module

Check out this link, in particular the Modules section:

http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/organizing-functions/

> Here's a module that contains two functions:

```
module MathStuff = 

    let add x y  = x + y
    let subtract x y  = x - y
```

> Behind the scenes, the F#
>   compiler creates a static class with static methods. So the C#
>   equivalent would be:

```
static class MathStuff
{
    static public int add(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }

    static public int subtract(int x, int y)
    {
        return x - y;
    }
}
```

Comment: But the accepted answer shows that static members in classes are possible.  This implementation detail doesn't seem quite relevant to the question.

Comment: Why use types when you can use modules? I prefer this answer

Comment: It may not be the "correct" answer, but it is a useful one.